# Override the System package in mean.io

Tags: angularjs, mean.io

Q1) I need help with overriding System package in mean.io? I am trying to create my own home page.

So I did this

```
angular.module('mean.mysystem', ['mean.system'])
  .config(['$viewPathProvider',
   function($viewPathProvider) {
    $viewPathProvider.override('system/views/index.html', 'mysystem/views/index.html');
   }
]);
```

I get following error http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/ng/areq?p0=MysystemController&p1=not+aNaNunction%2C+got+undefined

Can anyone suggest a resolution or a better way to do this?

Q2) Also, is this the right way to extend a package

```
Mysystem.register(function(app, auth, database, System) {
```

Does mean know the package to extend from a variable name?

Answer (score 4):

Don't know why, but removing the ['mean.system'] worked for me. Something as below,

```
angular.module('mean.mysystem')
  .config(['$viewPathProvider',
   function($viewPathProvider) {
    $viewPathProvider.override('system/views/index.html', 'mysystem/views/index.html');
   }
]);
```

---

This might be the why: "angular.module('mean.mysystem', ['mean.system'])" creates a new module which probably is in conflict with the one MEAN creates during package registration.

- Creation versus Retrieval
  Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module.
  See detail @ https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module
- Angular Modules and Dependencies
  Every package registration automatically creates a corresponding angular module of the form mean.[package-name]
  See detail @ https://github.com/linnovate/mean#angular-modules-and-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You can just add:

```
$stateProvider
      .state('/', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'youPackage/views/index.html'
      });
```

into your routes file.

`$viewPathProvider` not exist in older version of `mean.io`, for example in this used by openshift quickstart.